# Handle return key of bluetooth keyboard for number pad

Tags: ios, numpad, bluetooth-keyboard

In the app I am performing some action on custom done button that is added on the Number pad, as number pad does not have return key. Now, the problem is when hardware keyboard is attached I am not able to handle the return key press on hardware keyboard in case of Number pad. Is there any way to receive return press event of external bluetooth keyboard for number pad textfield?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a UITextField for input, you can implement it's delegate method, which should work for hardware and software keyboard return key...

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {

    // Return was pressed, do something here

}
```